# How to display input value next to each other in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I am building a calculator.
I am able to display a single input value for each click but I stuck with display input value next to each other. For example, if I click 1, 2, 3, it should display (123) in the input field.

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
        var btn = e.target.innerHTML;

        $('#display').val(btn);
        }
 });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the input value on every click rather you should append

```
$('#display').val($('#display').val()+btn);
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
        var btn = e.target.innerHTML;

        $('#display').val($('#display').val()+btn);
        
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value='1'>1</button>
<button value='2'>2</button>
<button value='3'>3</button>
<input id="display"/>
```

Comment: What is `+btn` means?

Comment: btn is your variable and + is for addition of btn to the input value

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are overwriting your `value` of your display. Instead you want to append to it. You can do this by using:

```
$('#display').val($('#display').val() + btn);
```

The above line will get the current text in `value` and add the button to the end of that string.